# Improve curve fit to data in R

Tags: r, curve-fitting

Having trouble fitting an appropriate curve to this data.

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61, 71, 
81, 91, 110, 210, 310, 410, 510, 610, 710, 810, 910, 1100, 2100, 
3100, 4100, 5100, 6100, 7100, 8100, 9100)

y <- c(75, 84, 85, 89, 88, 91, 92, 92, 93, 92, 94, 95, 95, 96, 95, 
95, 94, 97, 97, 97, 98, 98, 98, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 
99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99)
```

Tried so far:

```
fit1 <- lm(y~log(x)+I(1/x))
fit2 <- lm(y~log(x)+I(1/x)+x)

plot(x,y, log="x")
lines(0.01:10000, predict(fit1, newdata = data.frame(x=0.01:10000)))
lines(0.01:10000, predict(fit2, newdata = data.frame(x=0.01:10000)), col='red')
```

[image]

The fits are ok, but arrived at entirely empirically and there is room for improvement.  I did not fit loess or splines to be any better.

> The concrete goal is to increase the R^2 of the fit and improve regression diagnostics (e.g. Q-Q plots of residuals).

*Edit*: **Expected Model:** this is sampling data, where more samples (x) improve the accuracy of the estimate (y); it would saturate at 100%.

Comment: Is this really a coding question, i.e. is this the right place for it?

Comment: kind of hard to imagine that you're going to improve very much more on this. Can you say more about the problem context? What is the ultimate goal of fitting the model?

Comment: Agree w/Ben. Any effort to improve seems doomed to overfitting. You can always have an exact fit with a high degree polynomial but that's clearly unhelpful. Agree with other close voter that the goals are unclear because the constraints on fitting are not expressed clearly.

Comment: @BenBolker I appreciate your comments. What bothered me was the fact a high order polynomial doesn’t fit better and nor did a spline or loess.  I was curious if someone had a better approach.

Comment: Try `a + b * s * (x-1) / (  1 + ( s * (x-1) )**( abs( 1/p) ) )**abs(p)`. It works fine for me and has the property of saturation, as the data seems to saturate. If you want to saturate at 100 you may modify to `100 - b + b * s * (x-1) / (  1 + ( s * (x-1) )**( abs( 1/p) ) )**abs(p)`.

Comment: Different version would be `a * s * x / (  1 + ( s * x )**( abs( 1 / p)  )  )**abs( p )`

Comment: @mikuszefski Thanks for the attempts, how does one implement them into the fit? Does one use `nls`?

Comment: Uh, no idea, I do not use `R`. I do such things in python (hence the formulae), sorry. I can post that code, though.

Comment: @mikuszefski Sure, I'd take some python code! Curious if you set starting values for a,b,s,p, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R package `drc` has many options.

Here is a 5-parameter log-logistic model, which yields residuals lower than the fits in the question.

BONUS: It has a self-starter function, so you avoid the challenge of finding initial values for non-linear regression.

```
library(drc)
dosefit <- drm(y ~ x, fct = LL2.5())
```

[image]

Comment: OK, tried `99 + ( d - 99 )/( 1 + np.exp( b * np.log(x) - e ) )**alpha` in my code as well (fixing 1 of the parameters in the 5-parameter function). Gives more or less the same as `f`. This way, however, the parameters have a meaning.On the other hand one could only guess that it is about probability as your question gives only little (none whatsoever) information.

Answer (score 3):

This would be my function guess and according fit in python

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as so


def f( x, a, b , s, p ):
    return a + b * s * ( x - 1 ) / (  1 + ( s * ( x - 1 ) )**( abs( 1 / p ) ) )**abs( p )


def g( x, a , s, p ):
    return a * s * x / (  1 + ( s * x )**( abs( 1 / p ) ) )**abs( p )


def h( x, s, p ):
    return 100 * s * x / (  1 + ( s * x )**( abs( 1 / p ) ) )**abs( p )


xData = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61, 71, 
        81, 91, 110, 210, 310, 410, 510, 610, 710, 810, 910, 1100, 2100, 
        3100, 4100, 5100, 6100, 7100, 8100, 9100 ]

yData = [ 75, 84, 85, 89, 88, 91, 92, 92, 93, 92, 94, 95, 95, 96, 95, 
        95, 94, 97, 97, 97, 98, 98, 98, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 
        99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99 ]

xList = np.logspace( 0, 5, 100 )

bestFitF, err = so.curve_fit( f , xData, yData, p0=[ 75, 25, 1, 1])
bestFitG, err = so.curve_fit( g , xData, yData)
bestFitH, err = so.curve_fit( h , xData, yData)

fList = np.fromiter( ( f(x, *bestFitF ) for x in xList ), np.float)
gList = np.fromiter( ( g(x, *bestFitG ) for x in xList ), np.float)
hList = np.fromiter( ( h(x, *bestFitH ) for x in xList ), np.float)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot( 1, 1, 1 )

ax.plot( xData, yData, marker='o', linestyle='')
ax.plot( xList, fList, linestyle='-.', label='f')
ax.plot( xList, gList, linestyle='-.', label='g')
ax.plot( xList, hList, linestyle='-.', label='h')

ax.set_xscale( 'log' )
ax.legend( loc=0 )
plt.show()
```

[image: Three options]

Function `f` requires start values, `g` and `h` don't. It should be possible to write some code to guess the parameters, basically the first one is `yData[0]`, the second is `yData[-1] - yData[0]` and the others don't matter and are just set to `1`, but I did it manually here.

Both, `g` and `h` have the property that they pass `( 0, 0 )`.
Additionally, `h` will saturate at `100`.

Note: Sure the more parameters the better the fit, but if it is, e.g., a CDF you probably want a fixed saturation value and maybe the pass through `( 0, 0 )` as well.

Comment: Thanks, now to figure this out in R.  I've tried the standard non-linear function, but get some error messages about infinities.  How to you come up with the equation structure?

Comment: @Minnow How to come up with a function like this. Well, your data looks linear for small `x` and saturates for large ones. Most simple functions doing this are `( 1 - exp( -x ) )` and `x / ( 1 + x )` and `arctan(x)`. I also like `tanh(x)`. If the transition region ( the curvature part) does not fit very well, time taught me to fiddle with  `f(  x**p )**( 1 / p )`. That usually does not affect the linear part nor the saturation (if you take care about some details), but changes the curvature in the bend part.

Answer (score 3):

This might be an acceptable fit to the Gunary equation, with an R-squared value of 0.976:

y = x / (a + bx + cx^0.5)

```
Fitting target of lowest sum of squared absolute error = 2.4509677507601545E+01

a =  1.2327255760994933E-03
b =  1.0083740273268828E-02
c =  1.9179200839782879E-03
```

Comment: Nice as well, fits the data almost identical to my `g`

Comment: This is a nice fit.  Did you come up with this type of fit based on eyeballing the data or was there some other approach?

Comment: I used my online curve and surface fitting web application's 2D "Function Finder" to fit a large number of equations with three or less parameters. The web site uses a genetic algorithm named "Differential Evolution" to find initial parameters for the solver. It is an open source web app written in Python at http://zunzun.com if you want to poke around, links to the source code are at the bottom of every page.